# Python Scrape of table returns no data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to do some web scraping of this website ***https://www.playtogga.com/leagues/5969cefb9dbb4f0001b3b539/players*** and access the data in the table. My current code is:

```
https://www.playtogga.com/leagues/5969cefb9dbb4f0001b3b539/import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
        Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.playtogga.com/leagues/5969cefb9dbb4f0001b3b539/players"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "player-list"})

#Let's look at the first name in the Players list.
Players[0].text
```

But this gives the error below:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-b6ae920c924b> in <module>()
      1 #Let's look at the first name in the Players list.
----> 2 Players[0].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've used this code on a different site and that works fine, and when I check type(Players) it gives me bs4.element.ResultSet so it looks to be doing something.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? I'm very new to this so I guess I could be missing something very obvious. Thanks!

Comment: When I access that URL I see the welcome screen and no table. Perhaps that's the problem. Print out the resulting HTML and see what you actually get.

Comment: Yeah, redirects me to the homepage

Comment: Ah right, thanks a lot for your responses. To access the URL you need to be logged in, which I was when trying to run the code. 

However, if I print the HTML it gives me the HTML associated with the Homepage. Does this mean there's a problem in accessing the HTML of a page when you need to be logged in?